# Loop over multiple databases and save database name in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I am attempting to connect to a Pervasive server and loop over many databases inside of that server. I cant quite figure out how to save the results so that each chunk of results stores an additional column with the database's name. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


databases = ['db1','db2']
sql = 'select top 10 * from testdatabase'

connect_string = 'DRIVER=Pervasive ODBC Interface;SERVERNAME=1.1.1.1:1111;DBQ={}'
connections = [pyodbc.connect(connect_string.format(n)) for n in databases]

cursors = [conn.cursor() for conn in connections]

data = []
try:
    for cur in cursors:
        rows = cur.execute(sql).fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=[col[0] for col in cur.description])
        for name in databases:
            df['DATABASE'] = name
            #filename is getting overwritten
        data.append(df)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    for cur in cursors:
        cur.close()

df = pd.concat(data, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

ideally the output would look something like this:

```
column 1      column 2      column 3      DATABASE
random data   random data   random data    db1
random data   random data   random data    db1
random data   random data   random data    db1
random data   random data   random data    db2
random data   random data   random data    db2
random data   random data   random data    db2
```

Comment: Don't you have to do the query separately for the two databases?  Right now, you're doing a SINGLE query, then writing the database field multiple times.  That's not sensible.

Comment: Hi Tim,thanks for the response. Can you please explain in more detail? I am establishing a connection for each of the databases in the "connections" variable. Then I am establishing a cursor connection for the databases using the "cursors" variable. Then I am looping though the cursors variable and grabbing all records from the databases 1 at a time. Its very clunky and I'd like to simultaneously connect to multiple databases. Is there a better way to do this ? I have MANY DBs. Also on a side note, for this solution I ended up merging the df and getting the server name from another SQL query.

Comment: I think I see where you're going wrong.  Your `for cur in cursors:` is looping through all of the databases.  Within that loop, your `for name in databases:` is ALSO going through all of the databases.  I believe you need `for name, cur in zip(databases, cursors):` so you run both loops in parallel.

Comment: ah Thank you Tim! That was very helpful. I took that extra for loop out so Im just left with **cur in cursors:**  Also do you have experience w/ ThreadPool I was hoping to do some of this simultaneously

Comment: Maybe, but it you need to combine them all back together is one big DataFrame in a particular order, then you can't really do threads that might finish in an arbitrary order.  Python threading is good if you're (a) waiting for I/O, or (b) spending time in non-Python code (like numpy or pandas).